# Deploy Error on Opportunity

Tags: trigger

Could you pls explain why I get this Error? Thank you!
I try save

```
trigger ONOpp on Opportunity (after insert) {
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){

    }

}
```

And get this error
Error:(6, 5) Invalid loop variable type expected Opportunity was Opportunity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if you have a class named Opportunity.
In such case, `Opportunity opp` is a reference to the custom class Opportunity, while `Trigger.New` holds references to `Schema.Opportunity`.
Writing `for (Schema.Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {` will fix the error.

[Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespace_prefix.htm):

> you must fully qualify your uses of Schema namespace elements when they have naming conflicts with items in your unmanaged code. If your org contains an Apex class that has the same name as an sObject, add the Schema namespace prefix to the sObject name in your code.

By the way, I strongly advise against giving standard objects names to custom classes.